# How can I load bulk data from AsyncTask Resftful WS in Tab Fragment

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I need to load bulk data from a table which have 4k to 5k rows of data. I am using AsyncTask for calling the Restful WS and  getting reponse from WS in JSON format. I am calling this AsyncTask WS in a Tab Fragement. I have two Tabs Tab1,Tab2. I want to load the data in Tab2.

Is there any way , I can call the data in chunks and not at once.For eg when I select Tab2, WS should call and gets 500 records at first and display it on the page. Further user Swipes or Scrolls down, next 500 records should be fetched. Please help me how can I do. I searched a lot and got consfused !!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :1**

You need to ask server side to make pagination in API so you can hit your data accordingly.Then you need to call API again and again when you reach in last location.

**Solution :2**

You need to store whole data into your variable or local storage and then you can get data according to your need like 100 , 200 or 500 wise.Then you can to get DATA when you reach in last location.

So you need to integrate swipeable recycler view and it will help you for calling API and data from local.

https://github.com/chetdeva/swipeablerecyclerview

Comment: Thanks for response. The problem is getting data of 4-5k at a  time from remote Webservice is time consuming. So i want to get the data on multiple requests or once user done with seeing '500' records..

Comment: you are asking or telling ?

Comment: Asking!! precisely asking for solution :)

Comment: Yupe! but how?  Please see my Code here.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684263/duplicate-data-being-added-by-from-asyntask-webservice-in-fragement

Comment: talk to server guy for making pagination API for you then you can call API when ever you see 500 record

Comment: server u meant to say at database end or webservice end ? Can you please  give some link how can i make that ?

Comment: still what you want to do for pagination server or data base (its all depend on your requirement or what you want)

Comment: can u please help me with some piece of code, if i want to achieve this at webservice end ?